# java and website redirection detection

Tags: java

I have java related question...

Website www.stationv3.com gets updated daily (most of the time at least, it's kinda irregular). Every time I connect to a site using address www.stationv3.com (using a browser), it redirects me to it's subpage www.stationv3.com/date_of_latest_update.html

I'm trying to make a program that will pull latest comic from the site, but I am not sure how to find out it's exact address. But I know I'd be able to find out if I could somehow find out where where am I being redirected on every connect. Is that possible with java? I know it can do all sorts of quirky things, but I'm still new to internet related stuff...

I used exact site name just to make it easy for you to check outwhat's going on...
And also, I'm creating a generic code, one which could (with some tinkering) be applyed to any site that functions in that manner.

Comment: Figure out how the redirect is done. With Javascript? With a Location header? Once you find that out, we could maybe help you.

Comment: Don't you have the address in the URL where you are redirected to date_of_latest_update.html ?

Comment: I'm not trying to redirect, I'm trying to find out where am I being redirected. Nope, it just stays www.stationv3.com.

Comment: Nevermind the question, if I just put in "www.stationv3.com", java will just download the site I'm redirected to... I thought of it earlier, but I never thought it would actually work, so i disregarded the idea... Tried it now, after reading @Piyush 's comment...

Comment: The `HttpURLConnection` class will automatically follow redirects (3xx response codes) by default (see the `HttpURLConnection.setInstanceFollowRedirects` method).  This doesn't include Javascript or HTML-based redirects though, only 3xx redirects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import java.net.*;
public class ShowStationV3Redirect {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    URL url = new URL(args[0]);
    HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(false);
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    System.out.println("Response code = " + connection.getResponseCode());
    String header = connection.getHeaderField("location");
    if (header != null)
        System.out.println("www.stationv3.com redirected to " + header);
}
}
```

The above code snippet tells you what URL you are being redirected to.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could just fecth:

```
http://www.stationv3.com/comics/{yyyy}{mm}{dd}sv3.gif
```

and forget about the redirection problem. You can use this code (not tested indeed):

```
URL server = new URL("<put here the image URL>");
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)server.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setUseCaches(false);
connection.addRequestProperty("Accept","image/gif");
connection.addRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
connection.connect();
InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();       
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("c:/mycomic.gif");

byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];     
int byteReaded = is.read(buffer);
while(byteReaded != -1)
{
    os.write(buffer,0,byteReaded);
byteReaded = is.read(buffer);
}

os.close();
```

Comment: I could, but I don't know the exact address - it's possibble that comic wasn't updated for a while, so entering today date and trying to connect would fail. That's why I have to have the latest address.

Comment: @Karlovsky120 When you make the HTTP request, you could check it for a 404.

Comment: @Karlovsky120 got it. BTW did you notice that there's an RSS feed on the website which can also be used to get the latest image address? Maybe that could be an alternative.